# Proof for $\nabla \cdot \iiint A dv$=$\iiint \nabla \cdot A dv$

Tags: vector-analysis, formal-proofs

if $V=\iiint A dv$
Where $A$  and $V$ are vectors 
Then taking the divergence of both sides

$\nabla \cdot V$ = $\nabla \cdot \iiint A dv$=$\iiint \nabla \cdot A dv$

My mathematical knowledge doesn't exceeds calculus 3 and I found this result in a physics book.

Intuitively it's true but I'm asking for a rigorous proof of it.

Comment: Can you give an example, or the source of this? Note that the integration "eats up"  3 variables, so if $V$ is a function of 3 variables $V(x,y,z)$, we need $A$ to be a function of 6, i.e. $A(x,y,z,x',y',z')$. Maybe for example $A=|x-x'|^2+|y-y'|^2+|z-z'|^2$?

Comment: the source is introduction to electrodynamics by Griffiths chapter 2 section 2.2.2. The divergence of the electric field